# RSpec mocked object and (state) variables

Tags: ruby, rspec, mocking, zeromq

I am using the ZMQ::Poller in a Ruby app and would like to write some rspec tests. Since the poller offers a `register`-Method to register a socket, which may later be accessed using `readables`, I need to save registered sockets in my mocked object somehow.

I think a pattern for this would be like follows:

```
  @int_var = 'a'
  tst_mock = mock('Test')
  tst_mock.stub(:save_method) do |arg|
    @int_var = arg
  end
  tst_mock.stub(:return_method).and_return(@int_var)

  puts "##########"
  puts tst_mock.return_method
  tst_mock.save_method('b')
  puts tst_mock.return_method
  puts "##########"
```

Is there a chance to achieve 'b' being stored in @int_arg? And to access it later on to obtain the desired output:

```
##########
a
b
##########
```

Answer (score 2):

Your stubbing of `:return_method` returns `a` every time because that is the value passed to it when the stub was registered.

You want it to be dynamic, so pass a block to your stub that returns the correct value.

```
@int_var = 'a'
tst_mock = mock('Test')
tst_mock.stub(:save_method) do |arg|
  @int_var = arg
end

# Passing a block, defer calculating of response until needed
tst_mock.stub(:return_method) do
  @int_var
end

puts "##########"
puts tst_mock.return_method
tst_mock.save_method('b')
puts tst_mock.return_method
puts "##########"
```

Will output:

```
##########
a
b
##########
```